# How to use the 'click' method to go to the parent component

Tags: angular, typescript

When I click the button in the component `product-list.component.html`:

`<button type="button"  (click)='addProduct("add")' >Add </button>`

I use the method `addProduct` in the component `product-list.component.ts`

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-product-list",
  templateUrl: "./product-list.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./product-list.component.css"]
})
export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output() emitProductList: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  addProduct(name: string) {
    this.emitProductList.emit("add");
    console.log("add"); // this line is displayed
  }
}
```

The method is invoked but does not go to the component `product.component.html` The `product.component.html` component is not displayed.

product.component.html:

```
<nav>
  <a  (click)='goTo("list")' >List</a> 
  <a  (click)='goTo("add")' >Add</a>
</nav>
<app-product-list [hidden]='!hideList'></app-product-list>
<app-add-product (emitProductList)='goToAdd($event)' [hidden]='!hideAdd'>
</app-add-product>
```

This method `goToAdd` does not work (product.component.ts):

```
goToAdd(e:any){
  if (e === 'list') {
    this.hideList = true; 
    this.hideAdd = false; 
  }
  if (e === 'add') {
    console.log(' --- add'); // this line is not displayed
    this.hideList = false; 
    this.hideAdd = true; 
  }
}
```

How to go to `product.component.html` from the `product-list.component.html` component?

Thank you very much for help

Comment: put this `(emitProductList)='goToAdd($event)'` into `<app-product-list (emitProductList)='goToAdd($event)'>` then in `goToAdd()` method use `router.navigate()`

Comment: the "hiding" of components is very uncommon for angular and propably not what you want. maybe you should check out the Angular Router and everything about that. https://angular.io/guide/router

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think emitProductList is given to wrong selector.

Check below part once

```
<nav>
    <a  (click)='goTo("list")' >List</a> 
    <a  (click)='goTo("add")' >Add</a>
</nav>
<app-product-list (emitProductList)='goToAdd($event)' [hidden]='!hideList'></app-product-list>

<app-add-product  [hidden]='!hideAdd'></app-add-product>
```